# Cannot access my Pi by single level hostname on wlan

Tags: raspbian, wifi, dns

Here's my problem:
I made a fresh installation of Raspbian Jessie on my Pi 3. After choosing my hostname in the initial raspi-config (and setting up a lighttpd web server), I could ping my Pi from other devices on the local network with `ping hostname` and I could display my website from the network with `http://hostname`.
This is exactly what I wanted!

However, I then proceeded to configure the wlan connection (in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`), which worked in the sense that it does connect to my wifi. However, since then it no longer responds to `hostname` but only to `ping hostname.lan` (and `http://hostname.lan`).

My research has led me to find that, in `/etc/resolv.conf`, there is a line that says `domain lan` but any changes I make to that are automatically reverted back and the program/service that 'supposedly' generates this file (resolveconf) is by default not installed with Raspbian, and I couldn't figure out what generates this file instead.

What do I need to do to get rid of that 'lan' suffix and just be able to access my Pi with `hostname`, like I could before I fiddled with wlan?

Comment: Frankly this is a lot of uninformed speculation on your part. Most of the name resolution has **NOTHING** to do with the Pi, but whatever you are using to access it. Raspbian runs `avahi` by default, which is a [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)
and responds to `hostname.local`

Comment: @Milliways Of course it's speculation. But a lot? I mean, come on. Most of my post is just stating what I did so you have all the information. Anyway, my being uninformed is the reason why I post here in the first place. All I'm saying is that my Pi does _not_ respond to `hostname.local`, only `hostname.lan`. And it just so happens that `/etc/resolv.conf` has a line that says `domain lan`. Coincidence? Maybe. Best way for me to know is providing that information with my question.

Comment: My possibly exaggerated comment referred to your speculation about causes. You did **NOT** say "my Pi does not respond to hostname.local" `resolv.conf` is populated by DHCP (or other software), mine contains `domain iiNet`, which comes from the router, but still responds to `hostname.local`. The fact remains that your name resolution problem is almost certainly external to the Pi.

Comment: To be fair, I *did* say "my Pi responds only to `hostname.lan`". The "only" in that sentence implies exclusivity, i.e. that the Pi does not respond to anything else. `hotname.local` is something else.
So essentially it would be my router that is pushing that 'lan' domain to my Pi? If I were to connect the Pi on another network and reboot it, `resolv.conf` would be different.
In any case, I don't like `hostname.local` any better than `hostname.lan`. I would just like it to respond to `hostname`. When I look in my router, I see my Pi displayed as `hostname`, yet it does not respond to that.